# "Save as" on response from HTML form

Tags: html, angularjs, forms

I am working on a project where my backend returns a PDF file on a POST request, which as standard has a name, but I would like the client to be able to specify name and location of where to save the file. I am kinda lost, and all my searches end up with "html to pdf"-links, hope someone can help me.

What I do now:

```
<form class="pull-right" action="{{Api2PDF}}" ng-submit="generateJSON()" method="POST">
     <input type='hidden' name="body" value="{{JSONBody}}">
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="getPDF">
</form>
```

Comment: Try to send content-disposition headers in response.

Comment: Already done, it is set to attachment

Comment: Please show the corresponding directive or controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force download, set these response headers:

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: attachment
```

But this bypasses the users decision how he wants to handle PDF files in the browser. That's why I don't like that solution.

Comment: Well, that is basically what I do right now, because that is what I initially wanted, but it does not really solves my problem ;)